# Mapping of a Random Variable defined as Indicator function: $X=\mathbb{1}_A(\omega)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I need some help in understanding something about random variables mapping from $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.

Consider random variable $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{B} ) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) ) $.

Then, Let $X(\omega) = \mathbb{1}_A (\omega)$.

Now, we obtain $\sigma(X)=\{ \emptyset,\Omega, A, A^c \}$

I'm totally confident about all elements in  $\sigma(X)$, but could somebody please explain to me, how to understand the case of $\Omega$?

What I think is this:

$A  = X^{-1}(\{1\})$, then,

$A^c  = X^{-1}(\{0\})$

$ \emptyset \in \sigma(X)$ since it is a subset of all sets (other reason?)

What about $\Omega$ ?? is the case that $\Omega  = X^{-1}(\{\mathbb{R}\})$

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Have corrected the notation of curly braces according to comments below.

Comment: It is the case that $\Omega = X^{-1}(\mathbb R)$. After all,  any element of $\Omega$ goes to some element of $\mathbb R$, so every element of $\Omega$ belongs to the preimage of some real number.

Comment: One also has $\emptyset = X^{-1}(\emptyset)$. Also, it is true that $A = X^{-1}(1)$, but not that $\{A\} = X^{-1}(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I'm very bad at notation, and  have a poor background on set theory.
Could you please tell me the difference between $\{A\}$ and  $A$? what is the role of the curly braces? thx

Comment: $\{\ldots\}$ means a set that contains $\ldots$ hence if you write "the set $A$" you describe A while with "$\{A\}$" you mean "the set that contains $A$ as an element". So it holds $A \in \mathcal{B}$ while $\{A\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$. 

One $A$ is an element of  $\mathcal{B}$ while $\{A\}$ is a subset of it. 

btw… it also holds $\Omega = X^{-1}\left(\{0,1\}\right)$ 

and additionally: "$X^{-1}(1)$" is some lack of notation. It's a abbreviation for $X^{-1}(\{1\})$ because actually we consider the pre-image of sets, not of elements.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks. I'm really new on all this. Have no experienced this strictness on notation before. This will be good for me to become more mathematical and less engineer. Thanks.